# How to resize a sprite from center in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

Am gradualy increasing the size of a sprite then after it reaches a ceritain size it should gradualy reduce in size. The problem i have is that it's not resizing from the center.

```
private float size = 40;
private float v = 200;
```

In my update method i have

```
public void update(float delta){
    size += v * delta;

    if (size > 80){
        v = -200;
    }

    if (size <= 0) {
        size = 0;
    }

}
```

then i draw it

```
        sprite.setRegion(AssetLoader.atlas.findRegion("circle"));
        sprite.setPosition(centerX, centerY);
        sprite.setOriginCenter();
        sprite.setSize(size, size);
        sprite.draw(game.batch);
```

how do i make it resize from the center?

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that `setOriginCenter` sets the origin to the *current* center. So if you change the size, you'll need to call this method again. Did you consider changing the scale instead of the size?

p.s.: 
Spirte source link:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.java

Answer (score 0):

setOriginCenter method set value of

```
originX = width / 2 
originY = height / 2;
```

so this method should be called after setting new size(width,height) of sprite.

It's better to use setScale method for your sprite.